# Facebook like button and add a comment event

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I've got like button on page and I'm catching events edge.create and edge.remove.
I'm using this code from Facebook developers page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create", function(targetUrl) {
    console.log("liked");
  });

  FB.Event.subscribe("edge.remove", function(targetUrl) {
    console.log("removed");
  });
}
</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
```

But I can't find a way to catch events when user clicks **"close"** or **"add a comment"** button in popup.
I tried with "comment.create" and "message.send" and it didn't work.

Is there any way to catch these events?

Comment: No, I'm afraid it can't be done for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Marc Witteveen's answer and my answer at [Catching the close or post to Facebook event of the Facebook comment box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385986/catching-the-close-or-post-to-facebook-event-of-the-facebook-comment-box) for polling for the height of the comment dialog. This is working for me.